# How can I debug "Exception while resolving variable in template 'unknown'"?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I keep seeing:

```
DEBUG Exception while resolving variable 'exception_type' in template 'unknown'.
```

In my django logs, followed by:

```
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [exception_type] in
```

followed by what looks like a string representation of a a list of dictionaries containing the request, and my entire settings.py file.

Another example:

```
DEBUG Exception while resolving variable 'lastframe' in template 'unknown'
```

I feel like I just don't have enough information to debug this.  All I know is there's a variable called `exception_type` in an unknown template.  My code doesn't contain the string 'exception_type' anywhere.

How can I debug this?
Where should I be looking?

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Python 2.7.6
- Django 1.11

Comment: Is it happening in production ?

Comment: @itzmeontv yes, another example: `DEBUG Exception while resolving variable 'lastframe' in template 'unknown'`

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: I never did @MartinReguly. I think I just stopped logging template exceptions.

Comment: Could you please share, little more details like where and when you are getting the error. is at template load time or when start the server ?

Comment: python's debugger `pdb` has never failed me! Might be worth to setup pdb with `import pdb` and adding `pdb.set_trace()` statement to your code a bit before where you think its throwing the error, and then start the server and make the request that triggers the error. The "pdb" debugger will pause the execution of the code and allow you to step through it, inspect the values of the variables, and continue the execution.

Answer (score 1):

One of the variables in your code is faulty. I cannot see the code so I do not know which one. Exeption_type likely refers to a type of variable in your code or an exception to one variable via another. However, it is also possible that there is another file referenced in your code that contains a common mistake, such as forgetting to define it as global().

Answer (score 0):

The point wasn't variable `lastframe` or variable `exception_type` you gotta checkout your url, all of the urls, not just back-end url but also the front-end url.
Check out the front-end urls and middleware (if you wrote your own middleware files, the best check way is testing admin on your url).
I got the same kind of question, when I checked url and middleware, I solved the issue easily.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Pleas be concise and succinct while being descriptive enough that the original problem can be resolved using the data you present.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your Django project using `vscode` with the `vscode-python` extension you can debug your template files as below

Try to inspect your variable in `debug console` for example i have entered `switch_data` variable coming from my view

[image: Vscode Django Template Debug View]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33485818)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Pleas be concise and succinct while being descriptive enough that the original problem can be resolved using the data you present.